# Python Regex: Replace all urls in string with HTML links excluding .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a big multiline string that might contain lots of very different urls in any places of the line, like:

`La-la-la https://example.com/ https://example.com/
https://example.com/ la-la-la https://example.com/
la-la-la https://example.com/ la-la-la`

And I need to replace them all with `<a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a>`

**Conditions:**

- URL - is everything that starts with `https?://` and goes till whitespace/linebreak/end of the entire string.
- But. URLs, that end strictly with .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg in any cases should not be matched (Later they'll be replaced them with  tag)

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Is the input something like a load of text scraped from webpages? I'd guess, from this and your other Q, that there is probably a more efficient way to solve the bigger problem than search-and-replace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
def href(d, skip = ['.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg']):
  return f'<a href="{d}">{d}</a>' if not re.findall('|'.join(skip), d) else d

s = """
La-la-la https://example.com/ https://example.com/
https://example.com/ la-la-la https://example.com/
la-la-la https://example.com/ la-la-la
"""
new_s = re.sub('https*://.*?(?=[\s$])', lambda x:href(x.group()), s)
```

Output:

```
La-la-la <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a> <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a> <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a> la-la-la <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a> la-la-la <a href="https://example.com/">https://example.com/</a> la-la-la
```

Comment: I didn't know the lambda in `sub` is possible. TIL, thanks!

Comment: @AndrejKesely It is quite powerful, and much simpler than using string formatting or `f-strings`.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I don't remember how many times I did some clunky workarounds - this could've simplified so many things :)

Answer (score 1):

```
`badtags = ['.png', '.gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg']
 goodurls = ['https://', 'http://']
 for line in string:
     for word in line.strip().split():
         if(word[0:7] == 'https://' or word[0:6] == 'http://'):
             if(not word[-4:] in badtags):
                 // replace logic
`
```

This is a fairly simply way to do it, you may have to use a regular iterating for loop to be able to index your original array.